# Load applications icons and getting OutOfMemory exception while resizing

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Here is the code : (All executed async while showing a progress bar)

```
List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ResolveInfo app : apps) {
    String label = app.activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    Drawable icon = app.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    Drawable resizedIcon = null;
    if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        resizedIcon = Graphics.resize(icon, res, iconW, iconH);
    }
    AppInfo ai = new AppInfo(app, label, resizedIcon);
    items.add(ai);
}
```

Here is `Graphics.resize()` :

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, widthPx, heightPx, false);
b.recycle();
return new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmapResized);
```

Generally it all works fine, but I did get a report about out of memory exception while calling `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` (i'm trying to re-size to 32dp)
I read about handling and displaying bitmaps , but here, I want the app icon to be displayed immediately while the user sees the app name, and not just start being loaded. (which I can achieve by using `RecyclerView`)

Comment: How big are those icons? You have to remember than bitmaps take up a lot of memory (width * height * 4 bytes) so one have to be very careful while working with them, especially on low-end devices. Consider reading http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html.

Comment: You can use picasso with a custom RequestHandler. Example loading app icons here: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/android/processes/sample/picasso/AppIconRequestHandler.java

Comment: @ElDae , I have no idea what is the icons sizes as they are loaded, but this is exactly why I'm trying to resize them to a very small scale, the link you added is what I've read before submitting this question, however, its main idea is checking the dimensions prior to decoding the bitmap, while I don't think I can do this ..

Comment: @Jared, it looks nice but I can't see how it assists me, the problem is while trying to resize, the imag loading mentioned on picasa looks pretty much the same as what I'm doing ...

Comment: @SagiLow Did you get to solve this problem? in my case each drawable returned by app.activityInfo.loadIcon consumes about 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

when system can't satisfy needs of application specially resource you will get this error as you can see this is happening as you are running low on memory

you ca increase the amount of heap memory provided to your application (`process`) by adding an `attribute` to the application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` which is

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

your application tag would look something like this...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Although it will increase the memory provided to the application (`process`). it does not guarantee that it would be enough for the task you want to perform.

if you are trying to start a memory expensive `Task`, add this like of code

```
    System.gc();
```

This may free up some memory for you on the heap. but it completely depends on `DVM ( Dalivik Virtual Machine)` to deal with `heap`.

Make sure you call this before starting your heavy `task` otherwise it would be useless calling it after the Task has been completed.

if you are facing this issue on `emulator` you can try increasing the heap memory of the `AVD (Android Virtual Device)` like this

[image: AVD edit]

When dealing with bitmaps images try to get them in as small as possible they are the common culprit for `OutOfMemory` error.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of `largeHeap`, IMHO it's not the correct way to go, Android docs reflect that as well : `Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix` - http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html, It is not an emulator issue but a report from one of the users of my app, calling `gc` might be nice but not something I can rely on, I'm pretty sure this issue has to be handled by a better bitmap handling...

Comment: @SagiLow, What you are saying is right and indeed the images has to be handled, I will look into it

Comment: @SagiLow, did you create **AppInfo** class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the large heap attribute to true.

There is also a way you can use image loader in that image so the icon you get will be stored on the device.

Comment: Could you please say how to use the image loader?

Comment: `LargeHeap` isn't the correct solution for me (see my comment to Pankaj), I'll be happy to hear more about the image loader you mentioned.